# How to get the public folder mailbox where public folder belong in Exchange?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS api to get the list of public folders in java.
Public folders can only be created if the public folder mailbox exists.
I wonder how to get the public folder mailbox of that specific public folder, and to list also all the public folder mailbox available? Thanks